# Hierarchical query from two tables

Tags: oracle

Help me create a hierarchical query.
I have two table:

Table 1(dic_kgs)

```
KGS_ID    KGS_PARENT_ID    KGS_CODE
1                           A  
2              1            A0
3              1            A1
4                           B
```

and so on

Table 2(dic_kgs_strings)

```
KGS_ID    LANG_ID    KGS_NAME    KGS_ADD_INFO
1            1        Name1
2            1        Name2
3            1        Name3 
4            1        Name4
```

and so on.

I want to get result in the follow view:

```
A Name1
A0 Name2
A1 Name3
B Name4
```

I have writen only part of query:

```
select kgs_code
  from dic_kgs 
  start with dic_kgs.kgs_parent_id is null
      connect by prior dic_kgs.kgs_id = dic_kgs.kgs_parent_id;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `kgs_id` is the `primary key` of both tables (which is a little strange), join the tables before doing the `connect by`:

```
select kgs_code, kgs_name
from (select * from dic_kgs join dic_kgs_strings using(kgs_id))
start with kgs_parent_id is null
connect by kgs_parent_id = prior kgs_id;
```

alternatively look up `kgs_name` after the `connect by` (this approach can be helpful in more complicated situations such as if not all records in `dic_kgs` have a corresponding record in `dic_kgs_strings`):

```
select kgs_code, ( select kgs_name 
                   from dic_kgs_strings 
                   where kgs_id=kgs_code.kgs_id ) as kgs_name
from dic_kgs
start with kgs_parent_id is null
connect by kgs_parent_id = prior kgs_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Conventional joins seem to be working just as as well in your case.

try the following query:

```
select kgs_code, kgs_name
  from so_kgs join so_kgs_strings using(kgs_id)
  start with kgs_parent_id is null
      connect by prior kgs_id = kgs_parent_id;
```

It seems to me just a little bit nicer and readable than the [ones proposed in Jack Douglas's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4267/26577).